# map function wont render text correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to display Metatags from an Image with a Map Function. But when rendering the keywords from the image, it only displays the first letter of the first keyword and no letters from the other keywords. But when I console.log the keywords there are all displayed correctly.
I also have another function to add keywords manually using the UI and those are displayed correctly.

This is my Array. I'm using a Set to prevent duplicate entry's

```
const [listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu, setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu] = useState(new Set([]));
```

This is where I fetch the keywords from another function. The function returns a list like ["Home", "Sun"]

```
const fetchImageKeywords = async () => {
    setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu(new Set());
    let keywords = await getImageKeywords(imageUri);
    keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
      listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu.add(keyword);
      setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu(new Set(listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu));
    });
  };
```

This is where the keywords are getting rendered.

```
<Layout style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
              {[...listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu].map((keyword, index) => (
                <Card key={index} style={{ width: 100, height: 50 }}>
                  <Layout style={{ flexDirection: "row" }} level="1">
                    <Text>{keyword}</Text>
                    <Icon
                      onPress={() => {
                        listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu.delete(keyword);
                        setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu(
                          new Set(listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu)
                        );
                      }}
                      style={{ height: 23, width: 23 }}
                      fill="red"
                      name="close-outline"
                    />
                  </Layout>
                </Card>
              ))}
            </Layout>
```

I don't know why this simply task are giving me such a headache

Comment: You're calling `setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu` inside a loop (the `keywords.forEach(..)` loop), don't do that, you don't even need the loop, you can just use `setListOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu(new Set(keywords))`

Comment: You should also first create a `new Set` and then call `delete`, because now you delete from the original set

Comment: @Titus it's still displaying not the whole words. For Example: ["House", "Dog"] -> "H", " ". I don't know why it wont showing the whole word, even when they are correct within the set.

Comment: I'm not sure either. You've said that if you hardcode the `Set`, you get the expected result, that means that the problem is not caused by styling. The only thing remaining is the content of `listOfSelectedTagsFromTheMenu`. Make sure it actually contains what you think it does.

Comment: @Titus now I checked again and when I have ["House", "Dog"] in my list and both aren't displayed correctly e.g. "H", " ", I can add "House" once again (but not twice), so the first "House" must be something else. But console.log can show it correctly. I get the keywords from converting them from Binary to a string, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Yes, that can be it. You can check it using something like this `keywords[0].charCodeAt(1) === 'o'.charCodeAt(0)`. This statement will be `true` if the first value of `keywords` is `House`

Comment: @Titus I found the problem. My Set looks like this after some change: Set {"H", "", "o", "u", "s", "e", ";"}. Now I need to find a way to fix this. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: That's quite literally what Titus said from the beginning, together with his explanation of the fix.